# Converting an absolute path into a url

Tags: coldfusion

I have a path: c:\home\example.com\wwwroot\img\

I need to convert it into a url: https://example.com/img/

The thing is that the path is dynamic and therefore the url is dynamic. I have the path in a variable. I am NOT on the page in the path, otherwise I would easily be able to use ExpandPath().

What I have is the root url which I get like this:

```
<cfif isDefined("cgi.SERVER_PORT_SECURE") and cgi.SERVER_PORT_SECURE eq 1> 
  <cfset http_sec = "https://">
<cfelse>
  <cfset http_sec = "http://">
</cfif>
<cfset websiteurl = "#http_sec##cgi.http_host#">
```

This gives me the root: https://example.com

This where I am stuck.

So if the path is "c:\home\example.com\wwwroot\folder\sub-folder\"

I need to convert it into a url: https://example.com/folder/sub-folder/

Comment: Host headers are client supplied, so be sure to validate https://www.skeletonscribe.net/2013/05/practical-http-host-header-attacks.html

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<Cfset path = "c:\home\example.com\wwwroot\folder\sub-folder\">

<cfif isDefined("cgi.SERVER_PORT_SECURE") and cgi.SERVER_PORT_SECURE eq 1> 
  <cfset http_sec = "https://">
<cfelse>
  <cfset http_sec = "http://">
</cfif>

<cfset weburl = replacenocase(path,'c:\home\','','one')>
<cfset weburl = rereplacenocase(weburl,'(.*?)(wwwroot\\)(.*)','\1\3','one')>
<cfset weburl = replace(weburl,'\','/','all')>

<cfset weburl = "#http_sec##weburl#">

<Cfdump var=#weburl#>
```

Basically you need to strip the "c:\home\" and "wwwroot\" from the absolute path and convert the \ into a /. This is just one way to do this.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the file structure could be different on other servers. So "home" and "wwwroot" could be something else. I'm trying to cater for a completely unknown file structure.

Comment: *completely unknown file structure.* May not be that easy, when you consider how mappings affect paths.  Not to mention that even the reverse function (expandpath) gets it wrong sometimes.  Maybe take a look at Lucee's [contractPath](https://cfdocs.org/contractpath) and see how they do it?

Comment: @MarthinusStrydom If there is a logical pattern between the servers this can be done by using regular expressions. Can you give several examples of paths you wish to convert to an url? If the file structure is completely different on all servers and you cannot access the root path it will become very difficult. You could also take a look at https://www.petefreitag.com/item/630.cfm, this may be very helpful. You probably need to replace application.cfm with application.cfc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these variables...

```
Protocol = #getPageContext().getRequest().getScheme()#;
Domain = #cgi.server_name#;
Template = #cgi.script_name#;
Variables = #cgi.query_string#;
```

So for example:

```
<cfset path = "c:\home\example.com\wwwroot\folder\sub-folder\">
<!--- remove the site loc on disk --->
<cfset path = replaceNoCase(path, 'c:\home\example.com\wwwroot\', '', 'all')>
<!--- convert slashes --->
<cfset path = replace(path, '\', '/', 'all')>
<!--- put it all together --->
<cfset myURL = '#getPageContext().getRequest().getScheme()#://#cgi.server_name#/#path#?#cgi.query_string#'>
```